# Javascript : ReInitialize Global Variable without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, initialization, global-variables

I have a page containing form fields with menus. on clicking a button, the form fields should be validated and errors should get displayed in a row of table on a Modal window.

I have declared a global variable to capture errors of different field. Global variable is a string and the error gets added as rows as shown below

first I initialize a global variable var gErrorTableRow = "";

The same variable keeps get append with table row based on errors of particular field name like shown below.

```
gErrorTableRow += '<tr><td>'+sFieldName+'</td><td>Enter Non Zero Value</td></tr>';
```

the table row shall get displayed on a Modal window on clicking a button.

But the variable `gErrorTableRow`  is getting append with errors again and again  even after i re initialize the if variable 'gErrorTableRow = "" ;' after modal window show., on clicking the button.

How to re initialize this `gErrorTableRow`  variable without refreshing the page.

I re edited based on the comments, hope i am clear now.

Comment: just assign new value to the variable inside the attached event handler...

Comment: What has jQuery to do with this?

Comment: I think perhaps we're missing the question. Have a read of [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and see if you can edit the question to make it more clear. Unless, of course, the answer below does answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You simply run code assigning it a new value, for instance:

```
gErrorTableRow = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with the `+` in this following line

The + operator can also be used to add (concatenate) strings.

```
gErrorTableRow += '<tr><td>'+sFieldName+'</td><td>Enter Non Zero Value</td></tr>';
```

You can simply try by

```
 gErrorTableRow = '<tr><td>'+sFieldName+'</td><td>Enter Non Zero Value</td></tr>';
```

Comment: I want the variable gErrorTableRow getting append with error information of different types of  form data.  I like to re initialize this variable once the error are shown in modal window. the problem i face is this statement gErrorTableRow = ""; or gErrorTableRow =null is not getting the variable reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a global variable, add the errors to their container directly. When the user clicks the button, empty the container and reinsert all validation errors again.

Something like this:

```
function onButtonClick() {
    var errorContainer = $('#error-container');
    $(errorContainer).empty();
    var errors = validateInput();
    $.each(errors, function (index, error) {
         var row = $(document.createElement('tr'));
         var fName = $(document.createElement('td'));
         $(fName).text(sFieldName);
         var eText= $(document.createElement('td'));
         $(eText).text(error.Text);
         $(row).append(fName);
         $(row).append(eText);
         $(errorContainer ).append(row);
    });
}
```

The above code assumes that you have a method to validate input and that it returns a collection of errors.